# Matlab Error: "Undefined function or method X for input arguments of type 'double'" With Recursion

Tags: matlab, recursion, fractals

I'm trying to make Sierpinski triangles with recursion but I get this error:

```
??? Undefined function or method 'sierpinski' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

I understand that it has to do with Matlab not finding the path for my function, but the weird thing is that it can find my main sierpinski(x,y,n)-function but not the same function that I'm trying to call later in order to get recursion.

My code looks something like this:

```
function sierpinski(x,y,n)
...
sierpinski(x2,y2,n-1)
end
sierpinski([0,1,0.5],[0,0,1],4)
```

I would be very grateful if someone could help me with this :)

Comment: could you provide a bit more of the code as context? Also, the error message you get, does it occur when you invoke the function from the command window, or is it thrown as an error within the `sierpinski` code?

Comment: Is your directory where this function is present added to path?

Comment: `function sierpinski(x,y,n)
hold on

if n == 0
    fill(x,y,'r')
else
    x2 = [(x(2)-x(1))/2, (x(2)-x(3))/2, x(3)+(x(2)-x(3))/2];
    y2 = [y(1), y(3)/2, y(3)/2];
    sierpinski(x2, y2, n-1)
end
end
sierpinski([0,1,0.5],[0,0,1],2)`

My code is not ready yet so I know that I'm probably not going to get Sierpinski triangles using the code I have so far. Anyway I want to get something out instead of errors.

Comment: Sorry, I had to split my comment.
Alan: The error occurs within the code at `sierpinski(x2,y2,n-1)`. Now I get another error though `This statement is not inside any function.(It follows the END that terminates the definition of the function "sierpinski".)` at the line where I'm calling the function (last in code). Perhaps I'm calling it wrong? 

user1343318: I've pressed the button 'Add to Path' in a popup when I called my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the first error you report. It probably has to do with the file not being on the path. The easiest way to avoid this is to change the working directory to the directory that contains the `.m` file.

The second error you describe in your comment is due to the fact that you're trying to have a file that is a **Matlab function** and a **Matlab script** at the same time. Both have the extension `.m`, but the first contains a function definition (something that can be called with arguments, has local variables, and can return values), and the other one contains a series of matlab statements that are to be executed exactly as if they were entered one by one in the command window.

Do the following:

– Make a Matlab function file `sierpinski.m` which includes only your function code:

```
function sierpinski(x,y,n)
hold on
if n == 0
    fill(x,y,'r')
else
    x2 = [(x(2)-x(1))/2, (x(2)-x(3))/2, x(3)+(x(2)-x(3))/2];
    y2 = [y(1), y(3)/2, y(3)/2];
    sierpinski(x2, y2, n-1)
end
```

Save the file to the current directory or a directory on the path.

– In the command window, enter the statement `sierpinski([0,1,0.5],[0,0,1],2)`. The result is a figure window with a skewed red triangle. Not a Sierpinski triangle, but I guess the first step is done. ;-)

Instead of entering that statement in the command window, you can also make a Matlab script file. Edit a file with the name e.g. `run_sierpinski.m`, which contains the statement:

```
sierpinski([0,1,0.5],[0,0,1],2)
```

Again, save the file to the current directory or a directory on the path.

Now you can run the script, either by clicking the "Run" button in the GUI (green triangle or so), or by entering `run_sierpinski` in the command window. Either way, the result should be the same as entering the statement directly.